# Как правильно реализовать хранение данных в bar-коде?

Tags: c#, .net, qr

При разработке корпоративного приложения, работающего с документами, возникла необходимость реализовать хранение части информации в *bar-коде*. Идея следующая: некоторая часть информации, содержащейся в документе (на бумаге), должна храниться в *bar-коде*, который отпечатывается, скажем, на оборотной стороне документа. Подскажите, какой тип *bar-кода* лучше использовать, чтобы в нём можно было поместить как можно большее количество символов русского алфавита. Пробовал Open Source - реализации *DataMatrix* для **.NET**, но возникли проблемы с кодированием русских символов. реализовать это дело нужно на ***C#***. Спасибо.

Comment: В один QR code влазиет около 1450 букв кириллицы в utf-8. советую туда и копать. В любом случае штрих код (EAN) кодирует только цифры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [ZXing.net](http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/)

Согласно их сайту есть поддержка UTF-8, а сама библиотека работает под :

> ```
>     .Net 2.0, 3.5 and 4.0
>     Silverlight 4 and 5
>     Windows Phone 7.0, 7.1 and 8.0
>     Windows CE
>     Windows RT
>     Unity3D (.Net 2.0 built without System.Drawing reference)
>     Mono for Android
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Сразу начните определяться, чем коды будут сканироваться.

Если это кустарный сканер из смартфона - вебкамеры, будете иметь определенные неудобства.

Если это сканер в виде отдельного устройства, исходите из его возможностей к считыванию и передаче на хост кодов.

Разница в стоимости 1D и 2D сканеров - примерно 5-7 раз. Учтите это.

Может оказаться экономически целесообразнее хранить в штрихкоде только ID из базы данных.

- Штирихкод в формате code39 формируется простым набором нужных данных специальным шрифтом
- В него помещается 18 алфавитно-цифровых символов. Достаточно для любого ID.
- Сканеры, способные этот код читать - недороги и доступны.

Comment: В качестве сканера планируют использовать камеру. Хранить ID нет возможности, т.к. запись в базе должна формироваться исходя из информации, содержащейся в документе.

Comment: @klutch1991 а как формируется документ, в таком случае? Почему бы сразу не закидывать его в БД?

Comment: Документ формируется на клиентской машине при помощи отдельного приложения. Суть в том, что машины киентов изолированы от БД.